# Jquery toggling incorrect element ID

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, pdf

I have a multiple choice quiz with 5 possible points and one binary, yes or no answer.

I was getting frustrated with jsPDF and html2canvas, so I made a rather inefficient workaround that I hoped would function for me.

I saved an individual pdf for each certificate, and have access to them with an `<a href="PDF.pdf" download>`. I know that just opens the PDF on most browsers, but that actually does more or less what I want it to.

I think my difficulty lies in my Jquery.
Regardless of what score you get, it defaults to toggling the first link and giving you the certificate which says you got one point, and said yes to the secondary question.

Here's the HTML.

```
<div class="answers">            
    <input type="radio" name="q1" id="q1a"><label for="q1a">option 1</label><br/><br/>          
    <input type="radio" name="q1" id="q1b"><label for="q1b">option 2</label><br/><br/>            

<div class="answers">            
    <input type="radio" name="q2" id="q2a"><label for="q2a">option 1</label><br/><br/>          
    <input type="radio" name="q2" id="q2b"><label for="q2b">option 2</label><br/><br/>            

<div class="answers">            
    <input type="radio" name="q3" id="q3a"><label for="q3a">option 1</label><br/><br/>          
    <input type="radio" name="q3" id="q3b"><label for="q3b">option 2</label><br/><br/>            

<div class="answers">            
    <input type="radio" name="q4" id="q4a"><label for="q4a">option 1</label><br/><br/>          
    <input type="radio" name="q4" id="q4b"><label for="q4b">option 2</label><br/><br/>            

<div class="answers">            
    <input type="radio" name="q5" id="q5a"><label for="q5a">option 1</label><br/><br/>          
    <input type="radio" name="q5" id="q5b"><label for="q5b">option 2</label><br/><br/>            

<div class="answers">            
    <input type="radio" name="qx" id="qxa"><label for="qxa">Praise the sun!</label><br/><br/>          
    <input type="radio" name="qx" id="qxb"><label for="qxb">Nope.</label><br/><br/>            

<p id="endButton"></p>

<button type="button" onclick="getScore();">Finish</button>

<br/>
<div class="cert" id="cert0n">
<a href="Cert 0n.pdf">Download my certificate!</a>
</div>
<div class="cert" id="cert0y">
<a href="Cert 0y.pdf">Download my certificate!</a>
</div>

<div class="cert" id="cert1n">
<a href="Cert 1n.pdf">Download my certificate!</a>
</div>
<div class="cert" id="cert1y">
<a href="Cert 1y.pdf">Download my certificate!</a>
</div>

<div class="cert" id="cert2n">
<a href="Cert 2n.pdf">Download my certificate!</a>
</div>
<div class="cert" id="cert2y">
<a href="Cert 2y.pdf">Download my certificate!</a>
</div>

<div class="cert" id="cert3n">
<a href="Cert 3n.pdf">Download my certificate!</a>
</div>
<div class="cert" id="cert3y">
<a href="Cert 3y.pdf">Download my certificate!</a>
</div>

<div class="cert" id="cert4n">
<a href="Cert 4n.pdf">Download my certificate!</a>
</div>
<div class="cert" id="cert4y">
<a href="Cert 4y.pdf">Download my certificate!</a>
</div>

<div class="cert" id="cert5n">
<a href="Cert 5n.pdf">Download my certificate!</a>
</div>
<div class="cert" id="cert5y">
<a href="Cert 5y.pdf">Download my certificate!</a>
</div>
```

The "cert" class is set to `display: none`, so that the toggle allows it to display.

Here's the Javascript:

```
var totscore = 0;
var noanswer = 0;

var scores1 = [0, 1];
var scores2 = [0, 1];
var scores3 = [0, 1];
var scores4 = [0, 1];
var scores5 = [0, 1];

var praiseTheSun = 0

if(document.getElementById("q1a").checked){
    totscore += scores1[0];
} else if(document.getElementById("q1b").checked){
    totscore += scores1[1];
} else noAnswer = 1;

if(document.getElementById("q2a").checked){
    totscore += scores1[0];
} else if(document.getElementById("q2b").checked){
    totscore += scores1[1];
} else noAnswer = 1;

if(document.getElementById("q3a").checked){
    totscore += scores1[0];
} else if(document.getElementById("q3b").checked){
    totscore += scores1[1];
} else noAnswer = 1;

if(document.getElementById("q4a").checked){
    totscore += scores1[0];
} else if(document.getElementById("q4b").checked){
    totscore += scores1[1];
} else noAnswer = 1;

if(document.getElementById("q5a").checked){
    totscore += scores1[0];
} else if(document.getElementById("q5b").checked){
    totscore += scores1[1];
} else noAnswer = 1;

 if(document.getElementById("qxa").checked){
    praiseTheSun == 1
} else if(document.getElementById("qxb").checked){
    praiseTheSun == 0  
}else noAnswer = 1;

    if(noAnswer == 1){
    alert("At least one question was left unanswered above. Please ensure that all answers are complete.");
} else if(noAnswer == 0){
    alert("Your score is " + totscore + ".");
    if((totscore = 0) && (praiseTheSun = 1)){
        $("#cert0y").toggle();
    }else if((totscore = 0) && (praiseTheSun = 0)){
        $("#cert0n").toggle();

    }else if((totscore = 1) && (praiseTheSun = 1)){
        $("#cert1y").toggle();
    }else if((totscore = 1) && (praiseTheSun = 0)){
        $("#cert1n").toggle();

    }else if((totscore = 2) && (praiseTheSun = 1)){
        $("#cert2y").toggle();
    }else if((totscore = 2) && (praiseTheSun = 0)){
        $("#cert2n").toggle();

    }else if((totscore = 3) && (praiseTheSun = 1)){
        $("#cert3y").toggle();
    }else if((totscore = 3) && (praiseTheSun = 0)){
        $("#cert3n").toggle();

    }else if((totscore = 4) && (praiseTheSun = 1)){
        $("#cert4y").toggle();
    }else if((totscore = 4) && (praiseTheSun = 0)){
        $("#cert4n").toggle();

    }else if((totscore = 5) && (praiseTheSun = 1)){
        $("#cert5y").toggle();
    }else if((totscore = 5) && (praiseTheSun = 0)){
        $("#cert5n").toggle();
    }
```

I cannot fathom why, no matter what score I get, it defaults to cert1y.

Comment: At the end I see all of your `if` statements use `=` instead of `==` - you are assigning the values and this messes everything up.

Comment: `if((totscore = 0) && (praiseTheSun = 1))` Make sure you're using double or triple `=` marks when comparing. You're assigning values to `totscore` and `praiseTheSun` instead of comparing them.

Comment: Gah, thank you. I always mess up my logic. I suppose its a matter of continued practice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As some of the comments pointed out, you are assigning variables (=) in your if statements instead of comparing them (==). So here is why cert1y is the one that is selected:

The first if sets totscore to 0 and praiseTheSum to 1, and then compares them: (0 && 1) is false, so on to the else.

The second if sets totscore to 0 and praiseTheSum to 0, and then compares them: (0 && 0) is false, so on to the else.

The third if sets totscore to 1 and praiseTheSum to 1, and then compares them: (1 && 1) is true, so cert1y is toggled.

If you learn how to use the script debugger in any modern browser, you can step through the code and see this happen in real time.